# Zxing Barcode scanner plugin for phonegap android not working on nexus 7 which is having only front camera

Tags: android, cordova

Which Barcode scanner plugin for phonegap android is working for front camera also?

Comment: The ZXing 2.2 library is required.

Comment: @Slomojo can you point me towards/describe the steps for using ZXing 2.2 library with Phonegap?

Comment: @MikeMcKay no worries, I'll add a detailed answer.

Answer (score 10):

To make the Cordova/PhoneGap BarcodeScanner plugin work you need to go a bit further than you would with most of the other plugins.

I do most of my work outside Eclipse, so I'll explain how this is done from the Terminal and I'll add on Eclipse notes, if you need them (just ask.)

## Clone the plugins project

If you haven't already, grab the phonegap-plugins project from github:

```
git clone git://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins.git
```

(We'll assume they are cloned into: `/home/mike/phonegap-plugins`)

Also let's assume your project is called `/home/mike/CordovaProject` for the purposes of this answer.

and then copy the contents of `/home/mike/phonegap-plugins/Android/BarcodeScanner/2.2.0/LibraryProject` into `/home/mike/BarcodeLibrary`

This will contain the **zxing** library project as a usable activity, check that you have `AndroidManifest.xml, ant.properties, assets, bin...` etc. inside `/home/mike/BarcodeLibrary`.

I've checked this with a Nexus 7, the zxing library code contained in the plugin is working ok.  (Which is zxing 2.1 not 2.2)

It's possible to replace the zxing library code at `src/com/google/zxing...` with the code from the 2.2 download, but it's unnecessary and will require additional work / testing.

## Update the library to use Android SDK

You will need to update the `/home/mike/BarcodeLibrary` project use

```
android update project /home/mike/BarcodeLibrary
```

If you need to specify a target (SDK version) you can get a list doing: `android list target`

By the way this assumes you have the android sdk installed. Get it from http://developer.android.com/sdk/

If something has gone wrong, make sure you've copied the contents of `LibraryProject` into `BarcodeLibrary`

## Update your project

Now you can update your project to use the `BarcodeLibrary`. Copy these into your project:

```
phonegap-plugins/Android/BarcodeScanner/2.2.0/assets/www/barcodescanner.js
phonegap-plugins/Android/BarcodeScanner/2.2.0/src/com/phonegap/plugins/barcodescanner/BarcodeScanner.java
```

into `assets/www` and `src/com/phonegap/plugins/barcodescanner` respectively.

## Project Properties / Library References

Now you need to update the `project.properties` to include the `BarcodeLibrary`, edit it to include the new line:

```
android.library.reference.1=../BarodeLibrary/
```

(if you had more libraries to reference, you'd number them, to allow ordering for compilation dependencies.)

Note, if you wanted to include the library directly into your main project, you can just copy it into a folder, eg. `/home/mike/BarcodeLibrary/external/BarcodeLibrary`

The reference would then be:

```
android.library.reference.1=external/BarodeLibrary/
```

That's up to you, leaving it in the adjacent folder makes it easy to reuse, and maintain separately. Placing it in the project itself can simplify version control and continuous integration.

## Update AndroidManifest

You now need to update your `AndroidManifest.xml`

#### Permissions

Add these permission to `<manifest>` if they're not already included:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```

#### Features

Add these features to `<manifest>` if they're not already included:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>
```

#### Barcode Activity Node

Add this activity node inside `<application>` at the bottom.

```
<activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
            android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

## Config.xml

The **res/config.xml** for the project will need the barcode plugin specified. Simply add the following line to the **plugins** node.

```
<plugin name="BarcodeScanner" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner"></plugin>
```

## Done...

You should be able to go ahead and build the project:

```
ant debug
```

Or

```
cordova/run
```

Comment: Wow @slomojo - this looks great. I don't use eclipse either so don't worry about that. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Cool, I can't stand Eclipse, however, for any future drivebys, all you do is add the barcode libraryproject to Eclipse as a library project, and then in the main project, add it as a library reference. Essentially you're just editing `project.properties` with Eclipse's GUI.

Comment: thanks a lot...nice separation of concerns(plugin vs app) and especially cutting the crap out by not using eclipse...

Comment: By the way, it can make it slightly easier to manage a project by adding the library within the project root e.g. ./libraries/BarcodeScanner. From the standpoint of version control, ease of building (especially in a CI environment.)  Include it as a git submodule, or svn external (if anyone is still using that.) so that you can still maintain the library separately.

Comment: Just realized one thing that you forgot to include (i.e at least I needed it )was to add to res/xml/config.xml :<plugins>
 <plugin name="BarcodeScanner" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner"></plugin>
      </plugins>. This should be done in the project (not in library part). This will go unnoticed during compilation to form the .apk but the application will fail to find the barcodecanner and will give error:exec() call to unknown plugin: BarcodeScanner...correct me if I am wrong...